# How to keep a if condition in between when building HTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a HTML in javascript as shown below

```
    <div class="priDisRow">\
<p style="margin:10px 0 0 0;"class="pull-right total-rs total_204 ">'+price_without_additions+'</p>\
    </div>\
```

How can i keep a condition as shown below

In case if a keep a if conditon its throwing me an error in browser console .

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```
    <div class="priDisRow">\
    if(price_without_additions!=0)
        {
 <p style="margin:10px 0 0 0;"class="pull-right total-rs total_204 ">'+price_without_additions+'</p>\
    }
    </div>\
```

Comment: Are you definitely using jquery as the question tag says or just plain javascript? Either way you should look at using [`append()` in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`document.createElement()` in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) rather than building big blocks of html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using plain text of building HTML you may use arrays and [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operators for example:

```
var myHTML = [
  '<div class="priDisRow">',
  price_without_additions!=0 ? '<p style="margin:10px 0 0 0;"class="pull-right total-rs total_204 ">'+price_without_additions+'</p>' : '',
  '</div>'
].join('');
```

or for example strings with concatenations:

```
var myHTML = '';
myHTML += '<div class="priDisRow">';
if(price_without_additions!=0) {
  myHTML += '<p style="margin:10px 0 0 0;"class="pull-right total-rs total_204 ">'+price_without_additions+'</p>' ;
}
myHTML += '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var str ='<div class="priDisRow">';
   if(price_without_additions!=0)
    {
      str +='<p style="margin:10px 0 0 0; "class="pull-right total-rs total_204 ">'+price_without_additions+'</p>';
    }
str +='</div>';
```

and to display it

```
document.write(str);
```

or

```
  document.getElementById('ele').innerHTML=str ;
```

to display in an element as `<div id="ele"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var html = '<div class="priDisRow">\n';
if(price_without_additions!=0)
    {
    html += '<p style="margin:10px 0 0 0;" class="pull-right total-rs total_204">'
    html += price_without_additions
    html += '</p>\n'
}
html += '</div>\n'
```